# C#: Clear web application cache

Tags: c#, caching, session-cookies, browser-cache

In my asp .Net web application I had to recently change CSS styles, images etc. but when I published it on web server the users even after hitting refresh or logging out and logging back in again did not see these changes. On user's browsers (namely Chrome and IE) they saw all drop downs misaligned, images missing etc.

I have a master page in my application which references all my CSS. How can I ensure CSS changes gets reflected when I publish my web application?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You can force disable caching, but that slows down your users' experience. I've always just renamed my resource files so they are forced to re-cache. Change your Style.css to UpdatedStyle.css or something

Comment: @ShannonHolsinger "disable caching"??? If files (CSS/JS) already cached by user's browser there is nothing to kick them out of the cache short of changing url (as you've suggested - should be an answer, also this is probably duplicate of tons of existing questions)

Comment: Hi Alexi - I don't think it's true that you can't force-disable caching.  I agree it's moot here because the only present solution is to force a re-cache no matter what, but there are multiple methods to prevent a client from caching in the first place.

Comment: Thank you all for the reply. I am basically trying to make my CSS or image changes visible immediately without users having to refresh their browser or clear cache. Which is the best way to achieve this without sacrificing application performance?

Answer (score 0):

You could always let a package like [Combres](https://github.com/buunguyen/combres) do the work for you. It automatically adds a timestamp to your bundles when they change.